# converting char to list in R

Tags: python, r, list, email

I wrote a python script for reading mails' content and append to list and calling this python script in R. The problem is R is considering the list as one instead of two elements in it.

Here is my python script:

```
{
import sys
import string
import glob

def parseOutText(f):
    f.seek(0)
    all_text = f.read()
    ### split off metadata
    content = all_text.split("Bcc:")
    return content

def main():
    path = "D:/Hadoop/practice/machine_learning/mails/*.txt"
    files = glob.glob(path)
    file_list = []
    for each_file in files:
        ff = open(each_file, "r")
        text = parseOutText(ff)
        #text = sys.stdout.write(ff.read())
        file_list.append(text)
        ff.close()
    print(file_list)
    print(len(file_list))
}
```

and the output for this.

> [['From: xxx@xxx.com\nTo: xyz@xxx.com\nSubject: Hi\nCc:
>   abc@xxx.com\nMime-Version: 1.0\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n', '
>   test@xxx.com\n\nHi,\n\nYour problem is resolved. \n\nPlease reply to
>   this email and let us know if it is not working.\n\nThank you
>   \nCCD.'], ['From: abc@xxx.com\nTo: test2@xxx.com\nSubject: Hi\nCc:
>   xyz@xxx.com\nMime-Version: 1.0\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n', '
>   test@xxx.com\n\nHi,\n\nThis will not work out unless and until you
>   work harder.\n\nThank you \nCCD.']]
>   2

R code:

```
#setting the working directory to the mails folder
setwd("D:/Hadoop/practice/machine_learning/mails")
command = "python"
output = as.list(system2(command, args = "D:/Hadoop/practice/machine_learning/mails/testR.py", stdout = TRUE))
print(output)
print(length(output))
print(str(output))
str(command)
```

R output:

> [[1]] [1] "[['From: xxx@xxx.com\nTo: xyz@xxx.com\nSubject: Hi\nCc:
>   abc@xxx.com\nMime-Version: 1.0\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n',
>   ' test@xxx.com\n\nHi,\n\nYour problem is resolved. \n\nPlease
>   reply to this email and let us know if it is not working.\n\nThank
>   you \nCCD.'], ['From: abc@xxx.com\nTo: test2@xxx.com\nSubject:
>   Hi\nCc: xyz@xxx.com\nMime-Version: 1.0\nContent-Transfer-Encoding:
>   7bit\n', ' test@xxx.com\n\nHi,\n\nThis will not work out unless
>   and until you work harder.\n\nThank you \nCCD.']]"
>
> print(length(output))
>   [1] 1

How can I get two mails as two elements in the same list?

mails:

```
From: xxx@xxx.com
To: xyz@xxx.com
Subject: Hi
Cc: abc@xxx.com
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Bcc: test@xxx.com

Hi,

Your problem is resolved. 

Please reply to this email and let us know if it is not working.

Thank you 
CCD.
```

2nd mail:

```
From: abc@xxx.com
To: test2@xxx.com
Subject: Hi
Cc: xyz@xxx.com
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Bcc: test@xxx.com

Hi,

This will not work out unless and until you work harder.

Thank you 
CCD.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l = as.list(cbind(text1, text2))
```

Gives me the following output:

```
[[1]]
[1] " From: xxx@xxx.com\nTo: xyz@xxx.com\nSubject: Hi\nCc: abc@xxx.com\nMime-Version: 1.0\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\nBcc: test@xxx.com\n\nHi,\n\nYour problem is resolved. \n\nPlease reply to this email and let us know if it is not working.\n\nThank you \nCCD."

[[2]]
[1] "From: abc@xxx.com\nTo: test2@xxx.com\nSubject: Hi\nCc: xyz@xxx.com\nMime-Version: 1.0\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\nBcc: test@xxx.com\n\nHi,\n\nThis will not work out unless and until you work harder.\n\nThank you \nCCD."
```

Comment: Hi @datahero,   I could not understand where should I call this cbind? At system2 where I would be calling python script? These two mails were coming as a list to output variable. or am I missing something? Please suggest.

Comment: Hi @venkat, could you give me your exact input, please? I will try to adapt my answer according to it. cheers.

Comment: Hi @datahero, my input is the files that are existing in the directory mentioned. Right now I have created two text files (mails) and looping them, reading and adding the content to the list in python. Input in R file, is the output from python script.